Radix sort slower than expected compared to standard sort
I've implemented two versions of radix sort (the version that allows sorting integers whose values go up to n² where n is the size of the list to sort) in Python for benchmarking against the standard sort (Timsort). I'm using PyPy for a fairer comparison.
Surprisingly my radix sort implementation, even without using a hashmap (using a direct access array instead), is slower than the standard sort even for larger input sizes. There is micro optimisation that I'm lacking since O(n) should eventually beat O(nlogn). I'm seeking advice to achieve better performance. I'm doing this for learning purposes, therefore I'm not looking for built-ins, libraries, or C-compiled code to call from Python.
Are there micro-optimisations I could bring? Is my code really O(n)?

My code takes up to 10 seconds to run on an AMD Ryzen 9 7950X CPU:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time
from collections import defaultdict

def radix_sort(arr, size):
    least_sig_digit = defaultdict(list)
    for num in arr:
        q, r = divmod(num, size)
        least_sig_digit[r].append(q)
    highest_sig_digit = defaultdict(list)
    for k in range(size):  # k goes in order of lowest significant digit
        for q in least_sig_digit[k]:
            highest_sig_digit[q].append(q*size+k)
    i: int = 0
    for k in range(size):
        for num in highest_sig_digit[k]:
            arr[i] = num
            i += 1
    return arr

def radix_sort_no_hashmap(arr, size):
    least_sig_digit = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for num in arr:
        q, r = divmod(num, size)
        least_sig_digit[r].append(q)
    highest_sig_digit = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for k in range(size):  # k goes in order of lowest significant digit
        for q in least_sig_digit[k]:
            highest_sig_digit[q].append(q*size+k)
    i: int = 0
    for k in range(size):
        for num in highest_sig_digit[k]:
            arr[i] = num
            i += 1
    return arr


def benchmark_sorting_algorithms():
    sizes = [1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 10000000]
    radix_times = []
    radix_sort_no_hashmap_times = []
    std_sort_times = []

    for size in sizes:
        array = random.sample(range(1, size**2), size)

        new_arr = array.copy()
        start_time = time.time()
        a = radix_sort(new_arr, size)
        radix_times.append(time.time() - start_time)

        new_arr = array.copy()
        start_time = time.time()
        b = radix_sort_no_hashmap(new_arr, size)
        radix_sort_no_hashmap_times.append(time.time() - start_time)

        new_arr = array.copy()
        start_time = time.time()
        c = sorted(new_arr)
        std_sort_times.append(time.time() - start_time)

        for k in range(len(array)):
            assert a[k] == b[k] == c[k]

    return sizes, radix_times, std_sort_times, radix_sort_no_hashmap_times


sizes, radix_times, std_sort_times, radix_sort_no_hashmap_times = benchmark_sorting_algorithms()

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(sizes, radix_times, label='Radix Sort (O(n))')
plt.plot(sizes, std_sort_times, label='Standard Sort (O(nlogn))')
plt.plot(sizes, radix_sort_no_hashmap_times, label='Radix Sort (O(n)) - No Hashmap')
plt.xlabel('Input size (n)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('Radix Sort vs Standard Sort')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

The same question was posted here in CPP following the advice of @user24714692.

Python's TimSort is extremely efficient, you should be happy just to be in the neighborhood.

@MarkRansom are there some efficiency things they use I could use?

In Python specifically, wouldn't built-in sort be faster than any hand-written sort? Because the former is implemented in a lower-level language, but the latter has to move Python objects around etc.

@mark But it's still linearithmic and fairly complicated.

@Gassa What lower level language?

@Gassa That's why I use pypy, it should be able to do JIT compilation

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Aha, so in PyPy, they are the same level of compiledness. Alright then, I retract my point.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I suggest to add the pypy tag, as this might be due to things specific to PyPy. (I for example have no idea what's fast/slow in PyPy, what efficiency "mistakes" one can make there.)

@nocomment thanks for the suggestion. I do also welcome any suggestion for it to be faster with Python though. I just didn't include it since the .sort of Python is just that good that I don't believe i can beat it without JIT.

The source for TimSort should be freely available, you could study it to see what they do.  It's likely a lot more than just one thing.  I do know for example that it detects pre-sorted sequences and skips over them in further passes.

@MarkRansom With such random data, such pre-sorted sequences are short and not noteworthy.

Here's a version that seems about 1.5-2.5 times as fast as yours in current CPython and some old PyPy (I hope you can include it in your benchmark/plot). I imagine it might be even more beneficial in C++.
It avoids creating so many list objects. It instead uses linked lists in the form of arr-indices stored in three long lists. One linked list per remainder/quotient: first[r] and last[r] tell the ends of the linked list for remainder r, and next[i] tells the next element in a list. First/Last/Next are the same but for the quotient q.
def radix_sorted(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    # Sort by x%n
    first = [-1] * n
    last = [-1] * n
    next = [-1] * n
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        r = x % n
        if first[r] == -1:
            first[r] = i
        else:
            next[last[r]] = i
        last[r] = i

    # Sort by x//n
    First = [-1] * n
    Last = [-1] * n
    Next = [-1] * n
    for r in range(n):
        i = first[r]
        while i != -1:
            x = arr[i]
            q = x // n
            if First[q] == -1:
                First[q] = i
            else:
                Next[Last[q]] = i
            Last[q] = i
            i = next[i]

    # Output
    out = []
    for q in range(n):
        i = First[q]
        while i != -1:
            out.append(arr[i])
            i = Next[i]
    return out


# Demo / testing
import random
n = 10**6
arr = random.sample(range(n**2), n)
print(sorted(arr) == radix_sorted(arr))

Attempt This Online!
On the plot of OP:


First time I've seen Linked Lists that way. I assume it's faster (but probably not better memory-wise) than defining a LinkedNode class in Python because arrays are that much optimised? Thank you for the suggestion. The plot with your method can be found here: https://i.imgur.com/10RzPnX.png. It works really well really quickly. I added more sizes to have better estimates of the differences. Lesson learnt, when people say amortized complexity of O(1) for .append, it really really isn't as good as worst-case O(1) (except if that O(1) has huge constant terms of course).

It actually seems always faster (when using PyPy) than the standard sort. I should use timeit for less variance on lower values to be sure though.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Thanks for the plot. I don't know how fast a LinkedNode class would be, could be fast as well. Maybe using slots would help. I used my simple lists with C++ in mind, could you try that?

Yes absolutely. I've tried by defining a LinkedNode Class in C++ since I was curious about it after our discussion. Before I post it, would you mind giving a look at it? https://pastebin.com/y8V95hd7 It is indeed slower than all other methods (because objects are allocated on the heap I assume? But if I don't I get a SEGFAULT).

When using your idea (three arrays https://pastebin.com/9Bviux9C, arrays also allocated on the heap and not the stack) it works really well (not better than the built-in but a lot better than what we had until then); i'll update the plots but if you see something strange going on let me know! Returning output by value seems suspicious to me, among other things.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Looks alright to me, but I'm not used to C++ so I'm not sure about things there.

I edited the other post with all additional results.
